# Access ssd windows from hdd ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

I have my windows 10 intsalled on ssd and I installed ubuntu 16.04 on hdd. I have my files i.e songs, movies etc on windows, but for college work I mostly use ubuntu, so I want to access my windows files from ubuntu directly. How can I do it?

Comment: As usual, you need to disable the Fast Startup feature in Windows. Then, from Ubuntu just click the Windows drive. Important: Avoid writing to that drive from Ubuntu.

Comment: Writing to that drive shouldn't be a problem, normally. Of course, you shouldn't modify any system files or directories.

Comment: In addition to disabling Fast Startup, also disable Hibernate: *powercfg -h off*. Ubuntu will not automount, nor manually mount for writing, a Windows partition it detects as "dirty", i.e. left in a state where it has hiberfil.sys.

Comment: but my problem is that only, that there is no drive visible in ubuntu for windows

Answer (score 0):

Try FixParts

1. download Fixparts for Windows from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/files/gptfdisk/1.0.3/fixparts-binaries/
2. Unzip, on the command line (preferably from the admin) go to the folder with fixparts.exe
3. parallel open another command window, type `diskpart`, wait for the command line to start it, enter `list disk`, remember the number corresponding to your ssd (usually it's either 0 or 1), close this command window
4. we return to the command window from step 2, remember the number of your ssd from point 3, carefully enter the command `fixparts \\.\physicaldriveХ` (where X is replaced with the stored number), read what the program says, agree to everything when everything you will be ready to close the command window, from now on Linux will be required to see your partitions

Add - http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/fixparts.html